# Hiding dialog with spinner

Tags: android, view, dialog, crash

In my activity  I create an own dialog with spinner and edit box. The problem I got was orientation  change - I got exception each time, so:

1) I added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in my activity's part in manifest.

2) Implemented onConfigurationChanged in my Activity, which more less look like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChange(Configuration newConfiguration) {
    super.onConfigurationChange(newConfiguration);
    if (mMyDialog != null && mMyDialog.isShowing() ) {
    mMyDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Most times it works ok, but sometimes when I launch my dialog,  activate Spinner (launch Spinners Pop-Up) and change orientation I got:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:385)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:230)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:290)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:78)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:123)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:280)

So it looks like the dialog is not dismissed on time ?  Maybe I should override dismiss() method in MyDialog class and make sure all controls are 'closed' ?
My dialog class is created as follows:

```
mMyDialog = new MyDialog(this);
mMyDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try mMyDialog.hide(); function of dialog class

Answer (score 0):

with `mMyDialog.hide()`, it beahaves the same.

I also add that `this` in `MyDialog` constructor is a `Context` object.

Answer (score 0):

I had an [idea to prevent orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906513/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-orientation-change-when-a-custom-alertdialog-has/7082188#7082188) when dialog with spinner is displayed, but found that [there is no reliable way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock). The best solution that I found is to [replace spinner with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906513/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-orientation-change-when-a-custom-alertdialog-has/7121239#7121239). In my answer actually show how to restore spinner menu after orientation change, but you can easily choose not to do that.